# How remove extra space from cell of gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a gridlayout with two column

in column one: I have a TextView

and

in column two: I have a linechart

For better show I rotate TextView by 90 degree.
but, I see extra gap in left side and right side of TextView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridchart"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_yaxis"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:text="yAxis" />

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linechart">

        </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

I searched a lot, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: did you tried negative margins

Comment: No. can you explain more?

Comment: try  android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp" i textview

Comment: thanks. You're best.

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: Yes. thank you very much